# Prolog calls wrong rule. Does not backtrack correctly

Tags: debugging, prolog, call, rule, backtracking

Whats up?
I'm having some really weird problems with Prolog.
A recursive rule to replace an element in a list at a given index isn't always working.
My rule looks like this:

```
% Base rule - Stops when index is 1 and replaces the head with the element.
replaceAtIndex(1, _element, [_|_tail], [_element|_tail]).

% Recursive rule - Enter recursion for tail as long as index is larger than 1.
replaceAtIndex(_index, _element, [_head|_tail], [_head|_new_tail]):-
    _index > 1,
    _new_index is _index - 1,
    replaceAtIndex(_new_index, _element, _tail, _new_tail).
```

When I use the debugger from within my program I see **its always calling the second rule no matter what the index is**, but when I execute the exact same command outside my program it works perfectly well. It reaches index 1 but calls the second rule, and does NOT backtrack and attempt the first rule and fails all the way back up...

The rule calling the replaceAtIndex looks like this:

```
level_replace_block_value(_x, _y, _value):-
    current_level(_level_number, _width, _height, _blocks, _drawX, _drawY),
    coordinates_to_index(_x, _y, _index),
    _index_in_list is _index + 1, % the replaceAtIndex is not 0 terminated
    replaceAtIndex(_index_in_list, _value, _blocks, _new_blocks),
    retractall(current_level(_,_,_,_,_,_)),
    assert(current_level(_level_number, _width, _height, _new_blocks, _drawX, _drawY),
    graphics_update_block_value(_x, _y).
```

When I'm debugging its calling with index being 111.
When I'm replacing the `_index_in_list` with a constant 111 it works.

Anyone might have a clue why that happens?

Comment: Can you us some call to `replaceAtIndex` that actually behaves the way you describe? Ideally without the use of `level_replace_block_value`. Maybe the problem is that the two references to `_tail` (or `_element`) cannot be unified?

Comment: Ok, I've tracked it down in the debugger to index 3.  Whoops just a sec...

Comment: Ok, I've tracked it down in the debugger to index 3.  this is how it looks like: http://paste.ubuntu.com/835140/. When I'm calling it outside my program it looks like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/835141/ and the debug looks like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/835145/

Comment: This is extremely odd. What Prolog system are you using?

Comment: Very strange. Can you reproduce this with a simpler rule? What happens if you have a single fact `p(1).` and you query `?- X is 2 - 1, p(X).`?

Comment: Consulting this .pro: http://paste.ubuntu.com/835202/ and running `doReplace(2,  _new_list).` yields `_new_list = [0,1,10,3,4,5] ;
no
?- ` Can't recreate it S:

Comment: Editing the rule to include a maximum counting up instead of down to 1 also doesn't work...

Comment: Try merging the two clauses and using "if-then-else": `replaceAtIndex(I,...) :- ( I == 1 -> ... ; ... ).` and see if that gives a different behaviour.

Comment: You should remove the underscore-prefix from the variables you actually need, especially at `_index`...maybe your interpreter is doing a silly optimization. That's the standard convention for UNUSED variables.

Comment: I don't believe it. Rewriting the rule to this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/835252/ yields this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/835253/ __IT FAILES ON 1 IS 1?!?! It also failes on 1 == 1__

Comment: What about the other parameters? I suggest it isn't failing on 1 == 1 but one of the other parameters on replaceAtIndex. Try writing some simpler code with just the first parameter and testing that.

Comment: The code you just posted in the pastebin is wrong. Use `is/2` only for arithmetic evaluation. `_new_tail is tail` will not work.

Comment: Ya, i already fixed it with another subrule list_is(_list, _list). I'm happy to say it's now working properly, but I really think it should have worked normally! Why did the backtrack fail???

Comment: Try this: `replaceAtIndex(I,E,[H|T],[NH|NT]) :- ( I==1 -> NH=E,NT=T ; NH=H,I1 is I-1,replaceAtIndex(I1,E,T,NT) ).`

Comment: Any idea why the numbers im passing might not be numbers? 1 is 1 supposed to return true unless they are not both integers but literals. How do I make sure im working with numbers?

Comment: In your original post, the indexes must have been numbers, otherwise the computing of the next index would have failed. The question is rather, why would the 1 in the first clause not have been a number? I.e., why didn't the call with index 1 match the head of the first clause? I never used Amzi, so I have no idea why it would interpret it as something else.

Comment: try number/1. so, is the underscore prefix some convention of amzi! prolog? because if it behaves like in most prolog implementations (unused variables) i would say that that's the problem

Comment: @thanosQR: The underscore might be the problem, but, e.g., ECLiPSe and SWI would work with underscore prefixes. Only for pure underscores are fresh variables generated.

Comment: Amzi! should have no problems with underscores. The numbers are for some reasons treated as literals. At least that's my guess... I'll try the number/1 notation.

Answer (score 1):

Preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) by using the builtin predicates `same_length/2`, `length/2` and `append/3`!

```
replace_at(I,X,Xs0,Xs2) :-
   same_length(Xs0,Xs2),
   append(Prefix,[_|Xs1],Xs0),
   length([_|Prefix],I),
   append(Prefix,[X|Xs1],Xs2).
```

First, let's run the sample query that @magus used in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247417/4609915) to this question:

```
?- replace_at(3,0,[1,2,3,4,5,6],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,0,4,5,6] ;
false.
```

Does it work when the list items are instantiated later?

```
?- replace_at(3,0,[A,B,C,D,E,F],Xs), A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5,F=6.
A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5, F = 6, Xs = [1,2,0,4,5,6] ;
false.
```

**Yes!** What if the index isn't a concrete integer, but an unbound logical variable? Does *that* work?

```
?- replace_at(I,x,[_,_,_,_,_],Ys).
I = 1, Ys = [ x,_B,_C,_D,_E] ;
I = 2, Ys = [_A, x,_C,_D,_E] ;
I = 3, Ys = [_A,_B, x,_D,_E] ;
I = 4, Ys = [_A,_B,_C, x,_E] ;
I = 5, Ys = [_A,_B,_C,_D, x] ;
false.
```

**It does!** With monotone code, we get *logically sound answers* even with very general queries.

Comment: What part of the Question are you addressing?  This seems entirely polemical and not (three years after the fact) directed at the issues that were asked about.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you misunderstand the direction in which backtracking will take place.

The first "base" rule will be tried first for any call to `replaceAtIndex/4`.  If it fails, due to non-unifiability of the call with the "head" of the first rule, then the Prolog engine backtracks to the second rule.  [Unification failure might result either from the first argument (index) differing from 1 or from the third argument not being a nonempty list.]

Backtracking never goes in the other direction.  If the second rule is tried and fails, the call fails.

Of course things are complicated by the recursive definition.  The success of applying the second rule entails a new call to `replaceAtIndex/4`, which as far as the Prolog engine is concerned must begin attempting to satisfy that goal by starting back at the first rule.

I'd suggest adding a cut to the first rule, since by construction the second rule will never succeed if the first rule does.  But this is just an efficiency issue... why leave a choicepoint open that will never produce any further solutions?

```
replaceAtIndex(1, _element, [_|_tail], [_element|_tail]) :- !.
```

**Added:** I confirmed that your code works in Amzi! Prolog with a call like this:

```
?- replaceAtIndex(3, 0, [1,2,3,4,5,6], L).

L = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6] ;
no
?-
```

But of course you also see success when the code is called in standalone/interpreted mode.

So I have to suspect the "index" argument being passed in is not an integer but rather a floating point number.  Integer 1 will not unify with floating point 1.0, even if they are mathematically equal.

You can use the predicate **is_integer/1** to test for this in Amzi! Prolog.  The function **integer(X)** can be used to convert real 1.0 to an integer 1 by truncating the (nonexistent) fractional part.

Comment: See the third comment for the question. He posted two traces which show different behaviour. In one case, the first rule is inexplicably not tried (i.e., head doesn't match), and the big question is why.

Comment: hardmatch thanks alot for the detailed answer! I know very well how the backtracking works, thats why I don't get how come it doesn't try the first (base) rule. I know the list is not empty, so the 1's must be the problem. Thing is I don't pass it floating points, and in the rules that calculate the index I have number(_result) as the last line so it must be an integer. I could post my entire program so you could run it yourself, would that help?

Comment: @YarivLivay: You could post it here, but you could also post the code at the Amzi! Prolog forum.  I promise to report back here on what turns out to be the explanation, either way.

Answer (score -1):

Try `_index_in_list` set to `1`. Wouldn't the first rule get called then?

Sure the reason why the second rule is getting called if your `_index_in_list` is `111` is because `111` is greater than `1` ? The first rule only deals with `1` - as the first parameter says.

> When I'm replacing the `_index_in_list` with a constant `111` it
>   works.

What? You mean the first rule gets called? How can that be, the first param is `1`.

Comment: When im changing the call in my program from this `replaceAtIndex(_index_in_list, _value, _blocks, _new_blocks),` to this `replaceAtIndex(111, _value, _blocks, _new_blocks),` it works even though _index_in_list is 111! Look at my latest comment too, I put the debug dump.

Answer (score -1):

```
replaceAtIndex(I, Value, List, Result) :-
    RI is I-1,
    findall(Before, (nth0(B, List, Before), B < RI), Before),
    findall(After, (nth0(A, List, After), A > RI), After),
    append([Before, [Value], After], Result).


?- replaceAtIndex(3,0,[1,2,3,4,5,6], L).
L = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6].
```